# Vue 2.x + Laravel 5.4 not working in Explorer

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a project written in Laravel 5.4 and Vue 2 + Yarn 
I'm getting errors the following JS errors in IE (versions 9-11)

1. Syntax error (line where there is usage in const and arrow functions)
2. Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'

What am I missing ? I wonder if I'm misusing babel or perhaps something else is missing. I'm totally frustrated here because I already spent so much time figuring why nothing work properly in IE when Vue 2 components are involved. Any help or advise here will be highly appreciated !

app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
require('babel-polyfill')
Promise.polyfill();
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
```

my webpack.mix.js (tried to install babel)

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .babel('out.es6.js', 'out.js')
    .options({
        polyfills: [
            'Promise'
    ]
});
```

my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "build": "babel src -d lib"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "accounting": "^0.4.1",
        "axios": "^0.15.3",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-vue-app": "^1.3.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "laravel-mix": "0.*",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.4.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-vue": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
        "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
        "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
        "vue-events": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-strap": "^1.1.37",
        "vue2-filters": "^0.1.9",
        "vuelidate": "^0.5.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Vue app with IE and AFAIK, Vue just needs the Promises polyfill. But if you are using arrow functions, be sure you are using right babel setup. I think you need babel-preset-es2015-ie.

Comment: [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is not available in IE and you need to polyfill it. Transpiling will not automatically polyfill missing functions for you only translate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to resolve the problem by running the babel code, echoing the results to specific location:

my .bashrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel public/js/app.js > public/js/out.js
```

Then in the layouts files I included public/js/out.js file instead of public/js/app.js